# Pass a variable value as parameter to sqldf

Tags: r

I have a data set with id and dates. I take the today date into a variable.

```
today=Sys.date()
```

Now I want to calculate the latest data in my data set which is less than today date.

```
Date=sqldf(paste0("SELECT * FROM DATA WHERE MAX(DATE) <",TODAY))
```

I'm getting error and not able to resolve it.

Comment: I hope this is a very-simplified example ... otherwise, that query makes no sense, selecting either all or nothing. (Isn't `max` only allowed in the result set (left of `where`)?)

Comment: @r2evans Agreed, the query makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need single quotes around the value returned from `Sys.Date()`.  This should work

```
TODAY <- Sys.Date()
sqldf(paste0("SELECT * FROM DATA",
        " WHERE DATE < '", TODAY, "'",
        " ORDER BY DATE DESC LIMIT 1"))
```

This would generate the following raw query:

```
SELECT *
FROM DATA
WHERE DATE < '2018-03-29'
ORDER BY DATE DESC
LIMIT 1
```

This query will return the most recent record in your data happening before today.

Note that building a SQL string using raw concatenation like is generally bad.  But if you are just doing it from your R console for some data analysis, then it should be acceptable.

#### data

```
DATA <- data.frame(DATE = c(Sys.Date() + 5:10, Sys.Date() - 5:10))
```

Comment: Than you for the quick response. But I'm getting the below error      
  "Error in rsqlite_send_query(conn@ptr, statement) : 
  misuse of aggregate function max()"

Comment: @akrun What is the error you see when you run my code?

Comment: It is the same error vipinder mentioned earlier.   Looks like you have changed the code.  THis code is not yet completed.  May be some quotes missing?

Comment: I'm not in front of an R console.  If you can examine the raw output from `paste`, and if it matches my expected raw query, then this should work.

Comment: I think you forgot one quote.  I updated it.  Hope you don't mind

Comment: @akrun I appreciate this.  I will now "review" one of your recent posts.

Comment: Thank you so much Akrun and Tim:)